# How to create a form on the frontend of a magento store

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, forms, validation

## Synopsis

I Would like to create a form on the frontend of a magento store, I was considering using `Zend_Form` but before I do I was hoping someone could point me into the right direction using `Varien_Form_Data`.

The form is a simple contact form which will send an e-mail, this e-mail address is configured within the admin.

I would like the following:

- Ability to create A form /block
- Ability to validate this form using PHP (not JavaScript)

I do not want to add fields to the existing contact form, I want to build my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this in the end was to use a similar convention to `Mage_Contact`:

- I created a normal form in html;
- I validated this form using `Zend_Validate`;
- I set-up some configuration settings in the admin for recipient/bcc.